# How to subscribe to any or all taxonomy terms on one page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, notifications

I'm wondering about the best way to set up "subscribe to get email alerts"

I have a content type which is "tagged" with various terms from various taxonomies
and I want to set up a simple "subscribe to get email alerts" page, where users can subscribe to whichever 'terms' they like, so that emails are sent to them when a new item of the content type is created with the associated tags.

I have installed the notifications and messaging modules
which have enabled me to create a "subscriptions block", which is presented on the content pages with links like "Subscribe to: Content tagged with: XXXXX", which allows users to subscribe to a specific tag.

But what I really want is a page, which lists ALL available tags (terms) a user could subscribe to, with check boxes, so the user can skim the list and subscribe to any / all the tags they are interested in, in one go

I am struggling to work out how I might do that using the notifications and messaging modules…
perhaps I would be better off allowing users to 'tag' themselves with the same terms used on Content Type… and then set up a rule which fires an email to the user if new content (of the specific content type) is created with the same terms as they have tagged themselves with?

But I'm not entirely sure how I would go about that… or if there is a better / simpler plan?

I don't think this is a very complicated task - and am surprised I can't find links to similar requests / solutions online…

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: What did you end up doing here? I'm pursuing a similar solution and the closest thing I've seen so far is this: http://www.jacksonriver.com/news/message-stack.

Comment: i used flags and flag notifications

Comment: OK. My challenge is that i want users to be able to subscribe to entity references across content types. Would appreciate any insights if you think your solution could work instead: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158754/subscribe-to-nodes-with-entity-reference

Answer (score 1):

## Subscriptions

The [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module (with over 5K reported installs) is a typical solution used to setup such Subscriptions. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions. Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions. Users can also set an auto-subscribe function which notifies the user if anyone comments on posts they have made. Admins can turn this on by default.

## Total Subscription

The [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) module (only a bit over 100 reported installs)  seems like a possible alternative for such subscriptions. Some details about it (from its project page):

> Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.
>
> ... provides users the ability to:
>
> - Subscribe to a specific content type through the node page.
> - Subscribe to the related taxonomy terms associated with the node on the node page.
> - Subscribe to a specific taxonomy term from the term page.
> - Unsubscribe from any previous subscription.
> - Add a separate ctools content type - "subscription", which could be integrated with any panel page.
> - Add a "subscription" block to the any region.

Refer to its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2170825) for more details about it, or this [video tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jL41iZfxmpM) (without sound ...) that takes you through various admin screens.

Apart from that, to understand what this module is about, the [readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/total_subscription/tree/README.txt) might be helpful also.

## Module comparison

Some more details about how both modules compare (from the [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) project page):

> [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) provides the following features which are not there in [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription), namely it allows subscription to new comments in specific forums, or additions to some category of blog. More control on subscription management for user. Users can also set an auto-subscribe function which notifies the user if anyone comments on posts they have made which can be turned off by admin. But the biggest disadvantage of [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) is it does not allow anonymous users to subscribe, which [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) provide. [Total Subscription](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription) also has [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) integration.