# subscribe to nodes with entity reference

Tags: emails, flags

I'm building a music site and have an 'artist' content type that are referenced in product displays, articles etc. I want to enable users to subscribe to these artists and get notified whenever there's a product display, article, event etc. that references the artist.

I've been looking into the Message Stack module to achieve this (http://www.jacksonriver.com/news/message-stack), but haven't been able to make it work with entity reference.

Is this something anyone feels like helping me out with? Could be a very powerful feature IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flags + Rules + Views

I use something similar on a jobs site to allow users to subscribe to 'industries' (taxonomy) and be notified when a new job tagged with the industry is created.

In short:
install the Flag module, and create a flag for taxonomy terms.
This flag, when clicked, would fire a rule saying "Subscribe the user to this term" and this would happen with a nice Ajax link that does not reload the page.

Create another rule, saying something like "When new content is posted in X term, email all users who have flagged (subscribed to) that term."

Then build a couple of views:
A page of all the terms (if you need this!), showing the Flag links (these can be text, or you can style them as nice images using CSS).
The second view: A block, emulating a Subscriptions block - basically this block would appear on your 'Artists' pages, and it would show the terms together with their flag/subscribe links.

You could build a third block, to be shown on the user's profile page, listing the terms they're subscribed to.
You might want to use the Context module to control the logic of where the blocks appear.

Comment: Yes. I like this approach better than my suggestion

Comment: Using terms instead of entity references requires some restructuring of my website - But still this is a great solution, love how light & simple it is. If I've missed a way to do the same with entity references please shout

Comment: Hi @Olisb. Got this working perfectly - thanks for your help. Just one bug: On product displays (records) I've got an inline entity form to add tracks to a record's tracklist. It seems that the rule triggers an email notification on each track node referenced in the product display when I save the product display. In short, for one node I get up 10-15 emails despite the term only being used in the main node and not the referenced ones. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like the rule's firing on every instance of the term, not just the one related to the page... rules can get complex! you might need another loop... not enough space to share my example rule here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this module,

https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions

This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to nodes.

Hope it should be helpful.

Comment: I may have been unclear but I'm not looking to notify users on changes to nodes. The goal is to notify users when new nodes of various content types referencing my artist-entity is published. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The subscriptions module that latikas pointed out may work. There are other ways to accomplish this, perhaps in a lighter way. This is what I would try:

1. In your Artist content type add an Entity Reference field to Users.
   Be sure to selecte "Unlimited" number of values in the configuration
   settings for this field.
2. Create a Rules Link (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) called e.g. "Subscribe",
   and attach it to your Artist content bundle. The rule component for
   this Rules Link should basically "Add an item to a list". In this
   case the list is the Entity Reference field to unlimited users you
   added above, and the item to be added is site:current-user. Be sure
   to configure the Rules Link so that it shows only for authenticated
   users. This Rules Link will now show a link in every Artist content type.
   When a user clicks the link, the Rules Link will fire, and will add him/her
   to the list of users Entity Reference field in the Artist content type.

Once you have this working, you can simply create another Rule that fires every time a display, article, etc that references the Artist content type is modified. This Rule would basically loop through all the users in the specific Artist user Entity Reference field, and send an email to each of them notifying them of the change.

The only caveat of this method is allowing users to unsubscribe. I'm sure this can be done, but would require a bit more time, which I don't have right now :)

I hope this helps.